# Como criar uma div clicável em um tema do Wordpres?

Tags: wordpress

tudo bem? Estou trabalhando em um tema do Wordpress e precisava transformar uma imagem em um link porém não estou acertando qual comando devo utilizar nem onde devo inserir. 
O suporte do tema e orientou a mexer no arquivo herosection.php e eu gostaria de tornar a herosection-image clicável. Como fazer?

```
<?php
$out = '';
$hellotext = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_hellotext') != '' ? rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_hellotext') : '';
if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
    $out .='<div class="blog-herosection-image"> ';
    if( $hellotext != '' ){
        $out .= '<div class="herosection_text">'.$hellotext.'</div>';   
    }
    $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'full').'</div>';
}
$post_ids = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_posts');
$posts_per_page = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_posts_count');
$nav = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_nav');
$slideshow = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_slideshow');
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu link será feito de forma manual? Se o link for relativo ao conteúdo precisará explicar como está a estrutura e buscar ele de forma relativa também. 
Para inserir o link com o código, teste colocando dessa forma abaixo.

```
<?php
$out = '';
$hellotext = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_hellotext') != '' ? rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_hellotext') : '';
if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
$out .='<a href="#linkaqui"><div class="blog-herosection-image"> ';
if( $hellotext != '' ){
    $out .= '<div class="herosection_text">'.$hellotext.'</div>';   
}
$out .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'full').'</div></a>';
}
$post_ids = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_posts');
$posts_per_page = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_posts_count');
$nav = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_nav');
$slideshow = rwmb_meta('malina_page_herosection_slideshow');
```